Regularity conditions for properties of Hilbert transform
I want to use a property of Hilbert transform proved in the following paper, see Lemma 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01882.pdf.
My question is what does "sufficiently regular" mean in this lemma? 

That the transforms and integrations can be performed and give finite values.

@PaulSinclair I see, thanks. So, can we replace it with assumption that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$?

Everything is defined by integration. Continuity is more than sufficient.
